# Simple Membership on table with TPH discriminator column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I have class library with a Person Object, which also has two other types inheriting from it.  I was initially using this to extend the aspnetdb properties for a person, but then came across SimpleMembership security and have been trying to get it working ever since.

```
{
    public abstract class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// eg. AB123
        /// </summary>
        public string Uid { get; set; }
        public bool? IsRepresrentative { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Preferred First Name")]
        public string FirstNamePreferred { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string EmailAdditional { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Job Title")]
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public string PersonalPage { get; set; }
        public string ServiceArea { get; set; }

        //Profile items
        public int? PrefNewsItemsToShow { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return FullName ??
                   string.Format("{0} {1}", string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstNamePreferred) ? FirstName : FirstNamePreferred, LastName);
        }
    }

    public class ProviderUser : Person
    {
        public ICollection<Provider> Providers { get; set; }
    }

    public class SchoolUser : Person
    {
        public ICollection<School> Schools { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I have the following set in the InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyCommonContext", "People", "Id", "Uid", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Which seems to work, *if* I don't have it on a table with a discriminator.  But I thought the above was the idea, so that you can use tables which also contain other data.

There are two ways of looking at my question.
1. I get the following with the above setup when it tries to create the user from the AccountController:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Discriminator', table 'dbo.People'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

How can I resolve that?

1. *Or* the other way of looking at it, is how can I do what I want in a different/better way?

Answer (score 1):

This was a long time ago, but i just had this problem, and i have a solution, even though i hate it. Why it doesnt just work is retarded.

You can still use WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password) but add the Discrimator your self.

WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Discrimator = "Person" });

Answer (score 0):

What j_walker_dev said works fine, however, I'm not sure how correct it is.

In addition to this if you use it; you can then retrieve those types using the "is" keyword.

e.g.

```
var people = (from p in context.UserProfiles where p is Person select p).ToList();
```

EF knows which users are of type Person based on the discriminator name.

Lovely stuff.

Answer (score -1):

I get the same problem & i solve it this way:

> Please use WebSecurity.CreateAccount in place of
>   WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);

like this:

**Person in my case is not abstract.**

```
Person p = new Person();
p.UserName = model.UserName;
((PeronRepository)repository).Add(p);
((PerssonRepository)repository).Save(p);
WebSecurity.CreateAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

Thanks
Fawzy Malash